# what are the options to start a google app engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm writing a google app wngine application with python.. and there's some thing I haven't realized yet - 
Is the only way to start my app is by opening a web page ?
All examples are something like:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

which starts the app whenever an http request arrives..
i'm new with this, and pretty comfused

Answer (score 1):

The instances where your app reside can be resident or dynamic, resident instances will be always available no matter what, and dynamic instances will span as new http requests arrive to your application, allowing it to scale as more requests hit your app.

You can configure how many instances are resident to start with, there is something called warmup which can be programmed to be called before any live request is made, thus allowing it to "start" by itself.

Please refer to this url to find out more about this issue:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances

Answer (score 1):

That documentation *doesn't* show the app starting when a request arrives. It starts when you start the server by running `dev_appserver.py` as shown under "Testing the application". The server will keep running until you stop it.

Of course, it only does anything useful when a web request arrives, because this is a web framework and that's what you want it to do.